# Should useEffect have a dependency on the callback it will call (once)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a function (`loadJwt`) I want to get called once upon phone startup to load something from the phone's keychain:

```js
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const loadJwt = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const value = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
      if (value) {
        const phone_number = value.username;
        const jwt = JSON.parse(value.password);
        setUser({
          phoneNumber: phone_number,
          jwt: {
            accessToken: jwt.accessToken,
            refreshToken: jwt.refreshToken,
          }
        });
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(`Keychain error: ${error}`);
      setUser(null);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadJwt();
  }, [loadJwt]);
```

Does `useEffect` need to have a dependency on this callback or could its dependency array just be empty?

Comment: The dependency array of `loadJwt` is empty so it's okay to not add `loadJwt` to the dependency array of `useEffect`

Comment: @RameshReddy - That's true **in this case**, but is very much not true generally.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. I was strictly referring to OP's snippet.

Answer (score 1):

With that specific callback, you don't need it, though your linter may not know that and may complain at you if you leave it out.

The reason you don't need it is that the callback doesn't use anything it closes over that isn't stable. It uses `setUser`, but `setUser` is guaranteed to be the same function for the lifetime of the component. You've also asked React to give you the first version of the callback every time, and while that's not a semantic guarantee (`useCallback` and `useMemo` are just performance optimizations), it's likely the callback won't change. But the important thing is that even if it does, it's harmless to call the older one instead of the newer one.

Moreover, I assume you don't *want* the effect to run any time except at the beginning when the component is mounted.

**However**, unless you use `loadJwt` somewhere else (in an event handler, etc.), I would just implement it inside the `useEffect` callback rather than separately.